# Expression involving trig functions not simplifying

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a complicated function that returns a fairly simple result:

```
Sqrt[1/Abs[Sec[t/2]]^2 + Sin[t/2]^2]
```

I can see that this is equal to one, but when I try to simplify it with

```
Simplify[%, Element[t, Reals]]
```

nothing happens; it doesn't simplify. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need `ComplexExpand` before simplifying, which assumes that all variables are real in its transformation

```
ComplexExpand[Sqrt[1/Abs[Sec[t/2]]^2 + Sin[t/2]^2]] // Simplify

(* 1 *)
```